# error TS2345: Argument of type 'LooseRequired<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SkuStepperProps'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

error infor:

```
../../packages/components/sku/src/sku-stepper.vue.ts:28:65 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'LooseRequired<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SkuStepperProps'.
```

Type 'LooseRequired' is missing the following properties from type '{ readonly quota: number; readonly quotaUsed: number; readonly startSaleNum: number; readonly disableStepperInput: boolean; readonly stock: number; }': quota, quotaUsed, startSaleNum, disableStepperInput, stock

28 const { num, min, max, quotaText, onOverLimit } = useSkuStepper(props)
~~~~~

sku-stepper.ts

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import {  skuStepperProps } from './sku-stepper'
import { useSkuStepper } from './use-sku-stepper'

)


const props = defineProps(skuStepperProps)

const { num, min, max, quotaText, onOverLimit } = useSkuStepper(props)
</script>
```

sku-stepper.ts

```js
import { buildProps } from '@fast-plus/utils'

import type { ExtractPropTypes } from 'vue'

import type SkuStepper from './sku-stepper.vue'

export const skuStepperProps = buildProps({
  quota: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  quotaUsed: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  startSaleNum: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1,
  },
  stock: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  disableStepperInput: Boolean,
} as const)

export type SkuStepperProps = ExtractPropTypes<typeof skuStepperProps>

export type SkuStepperEmits = typeof skuStepperEmits
```

use-sku-stepper.ts

```js
import { computed, ref, watch } from 'vue'

import { showToast } from 'vant'
import 'vant/es/toast/style'
import type { SkuStepperProps } from './sku-stepper'

export const useSkuStepper = (props: SkuStepperProps) => {
  
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get some responses if you explicitly ask your questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more guidance.